# What is the significance of the order of keys in Linq Equals operator of the join clause?

Tags: c#, linq, join

The Microsoft documentation for equals operator of Linq Join says:

> With equals, the left key consumes the outer source sequence, and the right key consumes the inner source.

I don't understand what this means. I didn't think there was any difference which order you picked the keys. My usual criteria was to pick the shortest expression first. Now I'm wondering if my choice will affect performance.
So why should I pick one order over the other?

Comment: If you try to do it the wrong way around you'll get syntax errors, so you don't have a choice. It's to do with the way the LINQ expression gets converted into the extension method calls by the compiler. You just have to do it as per the documentation.

Comment: Even you will not be able to see the right key in intellisense when you try to type that in left hand side and the compiler will throw a syntax error like this. The name <right key> is not in scope on the left side of equals. Consider swapping the expressions on either side of equals.

Comment: I don't get syntax error when I swap the keys. The documentation just says that the left is the outer and the right is the inner. I does not till you what key to specify where.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out my problem.  I was reading C# Linq documentation but using Linq in VB. I assumed that Linq was the same in both language. But apparently C# is fussier than VB. So I was right in assuming that the Join clause introduces the inner range variable and that Equals has nothing to do with it. Apparently C# requires the keys to be in a certain order but VB doesn't care.